# Cmake basic library linking problem

Tags: linker, cmake

I have a simple problem with the linking of libraries with CMake (I don't know CMake very well).
My configuration is the following :

```
project/src/CMakeLists.txt (with all .cpp and .h files)
project/support/linux/gmp/include/gmp.h
project/support/linux/gmp/include/gmpxx.h
project/support/linux/gmp/include/libgmp.a
project/support/linux/gmp/include/libgmpxx.a
```

How to include the library gmp in the process of compilation ? (I am lost between FIND_PACKAGE, INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES, TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES, ADD_LIBRARY ... commands)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake is not so hard to understand.

**First Step**

Use [find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afind_package) to locate the libary.

```
find_package(GMP REQUIRED)
```

**Second step**

Use [include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainclude_directories) to include the libary header files.

```
include_directories(${GOBJECT_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

**Third Step**

Use [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) to link your binary against the libary.

```
add_executable(ExecutableName Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ExecutableName ${GOBJECT_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thank you but what I don't understand is how do you find the names of the variables ${GOBJECT_INCLUDE_DIR} and ${GOBJECT_LIBRARIES} : are they arbitrary names ? are they defined by the user when he runs cmake ? are they defined by find package ?

Comment: They are defined by find_package. See http://api.kde.org/cmake/modules.html#module_FindGMP

Comment: Thank you again. So my question is now : what are the command to find/link a library with no find_package (for example personal library called exlib with the directories exlib/include and exlib/lib) ?

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question for that case (SOF) is not a discussion board- than i will answer it.

Comment: Here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984479/cmake-how-to-link-a-library-without-automatic-search-function-find-package

Comment: In `target_link_libraries` I tried 
`${GOBJECT_LIBRARIES}` but it didn't work. Instead I simply added
 `${GMP_LIBRARIES}` and `${GMPXX_LIBRARIES}` 
 And it worked!.

Comment: This answer is ok, assuming the user has the FindGMP.cmake module on their system (which is not there by default).

Comment: I also didn't have `FindGMP.cmake`

Comment: The gobject reference is a misreading. Variables for GMP according to link are
`GMP_FOUND - system has GMP lib GMP_INCLUDE_DIR - the GMP include directory
  GMP_LIBRARIES - Libraries needed to use GMP`