# Linking To A Specific Library

Tags: linker, cmake, lapack

I am compiling a simple test program that makes use of `lapack`, however I have 3 versions of the lapack library installed (one from Apple in `/usr/lib`, one from macports in `/opt/local/lib` and one I installed myself in `/usr/local/lib`).

I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(delme)

include_directories(../../include /usr/local/include/boost-numeric-bindings)

find_library(lapack_LIBRARY NAMES lapack liblapack HINTS /usr/local/lib )
find_library(atlas_LIBRARY NAMES atlas libatlas HINTS /usr/local/lib )
find_library(cblas_LIBRARY NAMES cblas libcblas HINTS /usr/local/lib )

add_executable(delme test.cpp main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(delme lapack atlas cblas)

install(TARGETS delme RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

After calling `cmake . && make VERBOSE=1`, I get output ending with:

```
Linking CXX executable delme
/opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/delme.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/delme.dir/test.cpp.o CMakeFiles/delme.dir/main.cpp.o  -o delme  -llapack -latlas -lcblas
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clapack_dgetrf", referenced from:
      boost::numeric::bindings::atlas::detail::getrf(CBLAS_ORDER, int, int, double*, int, int*) in main.cpp.o
  "_clapack_dgetri", referenced from:
      boost::numeric::bindings::atlas::detail::getri(CBLAS_ORDER, int, double*, int, int const*) in main.cpp.o
  "_clapack_dpotrf", referenced from:
      boost::numeric::bindings::atlas::detail::potrf(CBLAS_ORDER, CBLAS_UPLO, int, double*, int) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

These symbols are in the `/usr/local/lib` and macports versions, but not Apple's version, which seems to be the one it's linking against.
If I manually add `-L/usr/local/lib` to the CMake generated file `CMakeFiles/delme.dir/link.txt`, then it compiles fine.

My question is, how can I instruct cmake to include `-L/usr/local/lib` in it's linking command (or some other alternative) so that it uses the version in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: Of the three library paths, are any of them in your PATH environment variable?  And in what order are they?

Comment: No, none of the library paths are in my $PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your are using the wrong libraries in your `target_link_libraries` call. The correct call is:

```
target_link_libraries(delme ${lapack_LIBRARY} ${atlas_LIBRARY} ${cblas_LIBRARY})
```

This will make the link command use the libraries that have been found by the `find_library` calls instead of the default ones.

Comment: Thanks. Now it compiles. I see from calling `make VERBOSE=1` that cmake instructs the linker to link directly to those libraries (i.e. `/usr/bin/c++ -std=c++11 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/delme.dir/test.cpp.o CMakeFiles/delme.dir/main.cpp.o -o delme /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a /usr/local/lib/libatlas.a /usr/local/lib/libcblas.a`), which is fine for just a few libraries, but I would prefer a solution that uses the `-L` linker flag. Is there a way to tell cmake to look in `/usr/local/lib` first so that I don't need to use `find_library` for each library?

Comment: You have to pass the relevant flags (`-L`) to `target_link_libraries` yourself. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984479/cmake-how-to-link-a-library-without-automatic-search-function-find-package.

Comment: Ok, so instead of using `find_library`, I can just use `set(libraries -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -latlas -lcblas)` and `target_link_libraries(delme ${libraries})`. This also compiles and seems much easier. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that one of the other library paths is in a cmake cached variable. CMake is finding that library version first.  After a library is found, find_library will not query again for the same library unless the cache is cleared.

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html?highlight=find_library), the command `find_library` uses the following order when searching for a library:

1. Search paths specified in a cmake-specific cache variable.
2. Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables.
3. **Search the paths specified by the HINTS option**.
4. Search the standard system environment variables.
5. Search cmake variables defined in the Platform files for the current system.
6. Search the paths specified by the PATHS option or in the short-hand version of the command.

Based off of these steps, CMake is finding a different version of the library on step 1 or 2.
Parameters exist to allow skipping some or all of these steps.

1. *Skipped with `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` or `NO_CMAKE_PATH`.*
2. *Skipped with `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` or `NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH`.*
3. *Skipped with `NO_DEFAULT_PATH`.*
4. *Skipped with `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` or `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH`.*
5. *Skipped with `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` or `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH`.*
6. *Skipped with `NO_DEFAULT_PATH`*

So at first it looks like you would skip steps 1 and 2, but according to Kitware, you should not put absolute paths under `HINTS`.  In regards to hints, the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html?highlight=find_library) states

> These should be paths computed by system introspection, such as a hint provided by the location of another item already found. Hard-coded guesses should be specified with the PATHS option.

Sure, it may work using HINTS today, but if you want to future proof your CMake files, I'd recommend following their advice.  So, your command would look similar to this to prevent CMake from performing steps 1, 2, 3, and 4:

```
find_library(lapack_LIBRARY 
    NAMES lapack liblapack 
    PATHS /usr/local/lib 
    NO_CMAKE_PATH
    NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
    NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
    NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH
)
```

Another option is to set one of the variables searched for in steps 1 or 2, but that is trickier to get right and and prone to becoming broken by future changes.

Also as a side note, avoid using `cmake .` which creates an in-source build.  Create another folder, like `build` and run your cmake command from there.  That makes it easier to delete the cmake generated files and start fresh.  Also it doesn't clutter your source tree.

Comment: OK, I've tried modifying the find_library command in my CMakeLists.txt as you suggested, but I still get the same behaviour (after removing all the cmake generated files), i.e. no `-L/usr/local/lib` in `CMakeFiles/delme.dir/link.txt` and undefined symbols when trying to link.

Thanks for the tip about building in a `build` folder, that was the next thing I was going to look into. I'm rather new to cmake, but have a fair amount of experience with complicated makefiles.